# Combine tensor matrix and sparse matrix of same dataset for splitting the data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch

I have an array and sparse matrix in tensor type and both are to be feed into the Neural network classifier. Since the data is too large, I need to split it batch-wise.

How should I club my sparse matrix and array together and then split train data batch-wise?

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[     0,      0,      0,  ..., 426017, 426017, 426017],
                       [   223,    310,   1045,  ...,     39,     14,    542]]),
       values=tensor([0.0730, 0.0722, 0.0911,  ..., 0.3244, 0.0883, 0.1659]),
       size=(426018, 10000), nnz=19173512, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

```
torch.Size([426018, 16])
tensor([[0.0154, 0.3296, 0.7500,  ..., 0.7628, 0.1643, 0.0092],
        [0.1041, 0.6322, 1.0000,  ..., 0.7612, 0.1629, 0.1283],
        [0.4987, 0.3387, 0.7500,  ..., 0.8692, 0.1879, 0.0150],
        ...,
        [0.1158, 0.6453, 1.0000,  ..., 0.6511, 0.2130, 0.0590],
        [0.0751, 0.2653, 0.7500,  ..., 0.7232, 0.1644, 0.0208],
        [0.4051, 0.3801, 1.0000,  ..., 0.8479, 0.2427, 0.1179]],
       dtype=torch.float64)
```

Above are two parts of same dataset in which one are numerical features(16) and second are tfidf features in sparse matrix.So in order to split it batch wise I need to club them together.
I know one function `data.utils.data.DataLoader` but dont't know how to combine my dataset to feed into it.

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani edited the question itself. Please help asap.